# Asp.net Membership.ValidateUser() Can it be more specific?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, membership

Membership.ValidateUser(username, password) returns a bool indicating if the login succeeded or failed..

How can I know more specifically if it was the password or the username that was invalid?

Thanks

Comment: Revealing that information to the user is a pretty big security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pretty easly execute MembershipProvider.ValidateUser() and then, if it were invalid, search for the user by name using the MembershipProvider.GetUser() method. If you found somebody then you could tell them that their password was incorrect as the user does exist.

That said, I would not want to give an attacker an easy method of establishing valid usernames in my system. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. I decided against it since I dont want to introduce security holes. Since on that topic I also want to call user.GetPassword() in my VerifyNewUser() action method to activate the account and log the user in automatically. I get exception:

"This Membership Provider has not been configured to support password retrieval."

I found where I can enable this but does doing so also introduce another security hole?

EDIT: although I dont see any other options since passing the password around in http requests is definitely no better.

Comment: It there actually a better way to get the password inside my VerifyNewUser() action method. I would really prefer to keep hash/salt approach but I need to "GetPassword()" in this one method. I dont want to compromise the whole system security for this one call =\ Perhaps send the actual hash value through http? Please advise.

Comment: I think the new user is logged in unless you have it setup to approve, you don't need to get at that password to get to where you want to be.

Comment: I do have it set up to approve. Im trying activate the account and log them in automatically. If theres no way to do this without compromise to security then I can redirect to login page but if there is it would be better to log them in automatically.

Comment: Well, if you are just automatically approving new members and logging them in then maybe you should just turn off approval or activation required.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, Revealing that information to the user is a pretty big security hole. 
If still not happy with it you need to write your custom Membership provider, please refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme for more details.